# Convert Java Google AppEngine app to Python AppEngine

Tags: java, python, google-app-engine

I'm a big noob to GAE, moderate level in Python, and moderate-to-rusty in Java.
I am looking to convert an existing and working GAE Java app (in the Google Play store and runs on Android) into GAE Python.
The end goal is to get it into the Raspberry Pi Store, so I'm assuming GAE Python would be the most seamless.

Has anyone done this, assuming its even possible?
Would it require a complete rewrite, or could I just write a wrapper/container?

Comment: How much code is it? How much time do you have to learn Python?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It'll be a complete rewrite.

However, the server side should be independent of the client.  You can have a python client for the Raspberry Pi and your server side code can still be written in Java.